# how to get daily profit from sql table

Tags: sql, database, ms-access-2010

I'm stucking for a solution at the problem of finding daily profits from db (ms access) table. The difference wrt other tips I found online is that I don't have in the table a field "Price" and one "Cost", but a field "Type" which distinguish if it is a revenue "S" or a cost "C"

this is the table "Record"

```
| Date | Price | Quantity | Type |
-----------------------------------
|01/02 | 20    | 2        | C    |
|01/02 | 10    | 1        | S    |
|01/02 | 3     | 10       | S    |
|01/02 | 5     | 2        | C    |
|03/04 | 12    | 3        | C    |
|03/03 | 200   | 1        | S    |
|03/03 | 120   | 2        | C    |
```

So far I tried different solutions like:

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT SUM (RS.Price* RS.Quantity) 
     FROM Record RS WHERE RS.Type='S' GROUP BY RS.Data
    ) as totalSales,
    (SELECT SUM (RC.Price*RC.Quantity) 
     FROM Record RC WHERE RC.Type='C' GROUP BY RC.Date
    ) as totalLosses, 
    ROUND(totalSales-totaleLosses,2) as NetTotal, 
    R.Date 
FROM RECORD R";
```

in my mind it could work but obviously it doesn't

and

```
SELECT RC.Data, ROUND(SUM (RC.Price*RC.QuantitY),2) as DailyLoss
INTO #DailyLosses
FROM Record RC
WHERE RC.Type='C' GROUP BY RC.Date 

SELECT RS.Date, ROUND(SUM (RS.Price*RS.Quantity),2) as DailyRevenue
INTO #DailyRevenues
FROM Record RS
WHERE RS.Type='S'GROUP BY RS.Date 

SELECT Date, DailyRevenue - DailyLoss as DailyProfit 
FROM #DailyLosses dlos, #DailyRevenues drev
WHERE dlos.Date = drev.Date";
```

My problem beyond the correct syntax is the approach to this kind of problem

Answer (score 1):

You can use grouping and conditional summing. Try this:

```
SELECT data.Date, data.Income - data.Cost as Profit
FROM (
    SELECT Record.Date as Date,
        SUM(IIF(Record.Type = 'S', Record.Price * Record.Quantity, 0)) as Income,
        SUM(IIF(Record.Type = 'C', Record.Price * Record.Quantity, 0)) as Cost,
    FROM Record
    GROUP BY Record.Date
) data
```

In this case you first create a sub-query to get separate fields for Income and Cost, and then your outer query uses subtraction to get actual profit.